# Get element by ID returns null

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, getelementbyid

```js
const data = [{color : "red"},{color : "blue"}, {color : "green"} ];

function libraryRoot() {
  load();
  return (`<div id="appDiv">
                    ${data.map(function(value){
                     return `<div><p>Color ${value.color} from libraryRoot</p>`
                    }).join("")}  
                </div>
              `);
}

window.onload = libraryRoot;

function load() {
  let a = document.getElementById("appDiv");
  console.log(a);
}

let defaultLayout = libraryRoot();
document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = defaultLayout;
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Hi Guys i modified the script as you guys suggested, but still the return value at the first instance prints null, and then it prints the div.can you guys help me where im going wrong.

All i wanted to do is i want to call the "appDiv" id and wirte a button funcion to it. like on click {//do  something}.

updated [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/vimaleurakaa/pen/wvaPbaW)

Comment: Check what you're doing and in which order. 1st you call `getElementById` 2nd you `return(\`<div id="appDiv">...` and store that string in a variable `defaultLayout` then you update the content of `#root` with something completely unrelated. Eventually `window` will have loaded and `getElementById` is called again. But at no point did you ever add `<div id="appDiv">` to the document; and in particular not  before you try to `getElementById` it.

Comment: which elements are changing?  If the "data" constant is changing, try  the below function 

function load(){
        let a=data
        console.log(a);
      }

Comment: Hi guys, I see I'm trying to fetch the I'd before its printed in the root. Sorry about the mess of the code and forget about the array. What I want to do is update the layout inside root div with some content from this function and then must be able to access the newDivId and write some function to those new div. How can I do this pls help :

Comment: Also is it possible to write functions inside the Template litreals if so then my value should return first and the ID must return a value. But I'm not sure how to do that :(

Comment: An Element has to exist before you can get it. You are attempting to get an Element that has not be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to access the element until it's written to the DOM.
Notice the word document in document.getElementById(). It's a method of the document API.
DOM stands for Document Object Model.

If you want to modify it before then then split your string literal into different pieces. Assign specific variables to important parts of the element.

Then modify them. Concatenate them back into one string and add them to the DOM.

Your code could use some comments.  It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.
Here I've modified your pen to show some different ways to handle each color in your data array.  You can do some conditional logic and return different template strings based on that. You could easily pass data object properties to another javascript function using the onclick attribute.

Hopefully this helps you get closer to your goal

```js
const data = [{color : "red"},{color : "blue"}, {color : "green"} ];

function alertFunction(color) {
  alert(color);
}

function libraryRoot(){ 
    return('<div id="appDiv">' +

                  data.map(function(value) {
                    var result = `<div><p>Color ${value.color} from libraryRoot</p>`;
                    if (result.indexOf("red") > -1) { // checking if the div includes red
                      return result;
                    } else if (`${value.color}` == "blue") { // checking if the objects color prop includes blue
                      return "<p>blue</p>";
                    } else {
                      return `<button onclick="alertFunction('${value.color}')">Button with function</button>`;
                    }
                  }).join("")
           
           + "</div>"
          ); 
   }
window.onload = libraryRoot;

document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = libraryRoot();
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi nick can you share any example on template literal and then explicitly call the load()function. All I wan to do is call the array elements inside the template literal and create a new div if certain condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are calling `load()` first, which is trying to access the appDiv node that doesn't exist yet. So rethink the order on that.

The second issue is that you never actually added the appDiv content to the DOM. You can use things like `document.appendChild(libraryRoot());` or something like that, though I have never injected a string as a DOM node - I use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for that. The link has some examples.

Comment: Hi mac, I'm really a beginner for javascript, do you have any reference on how to define the load() function inside the template literal.